# Visual Studio 2015 remote debugging on Windows 10 machine

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm trying to debug a Windows 8.1 App on a Windows 10 machine, in order to catch exceptions and errors.

I installed Visual Studio Remote Tools on the destination computer, but when I try to connect to it via Visual Studio 2015 on my computer I got a distribution error:

> Unable to connect to Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor computer ... Remote debugger version is non accettable.

Maybe the message is different in English, I translated it from the italian.

I'm used to successfully connect via Remote Tools to other computers and notebooks with Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, but that's the first time I got an error. What am I doing wrong? Is there a specific version for Windows 10?

Comment: Is msvsmon.exe running on the target machine?

Comment: Yes, msvsmon.exe is running and is recognizing the attempt to connect, but it shows an error message

Comment: Are you sure you installed the correct version of the remote debugging tools? I have seen this message when using the 2013 remote debugging tools with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @chuex, you are right and I'm a bit stupid ;)